# Leap year - Main is set wrong

Tags: java

Error: Duplicate local variable yearb
I been asked to put the month, year , day 3 separate variables.

You will send these values to a convertdays method that will return the date in the form of one long integer using the following formula:  your long year will be the sum of the year multiplied by 10000, the month multiplied by 100, and the day.  This is a formula used to put the date in a form that can be sorted (we will not be sorting dates, just putting it into a form that can be sorted).  Back in main you will print this labeled long integer.

```js
/* rayane seridj
 * 5-10
 * */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw2222
  
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
 int month, day, year,dates,yearb;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter Date in The Format mm/dd/yyyy : ");
    month = input.nextInt();
    day = input.nextInt();
    year = input.nextInt();
    
boolean yearb;
yearb = leap(year);
if (yearb == true)
System.out.println (year + " is a leap year ");  
    else 
    System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year");

  }
  
   public static int convertdays (int month ,int day, int year)
  {
    int yy,dd,mm,dates;
    yy =10000 *year;
    mm = 100 *month;
    dd= day;
    dates =yy + mm +dd;
    return dates;
   }

  public static boolean leap(int year)
  {
    if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 ==0 && year %100 !=0))
  return true;
  else 
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want and what you get with your given code ? You should be more clear about your question.

Comment: Error: Duplicate local variable yearb - it can't get more clear than that ...

Comment: can you help me set main

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

You declared variable `yearb` twice:

- at `int month, day, year,dates,yearb;`
- at `boolean yearb;`

A variable can only be declared once in a particular context (method, global, etc).

Try the code below (note a new variable named `isLeap`):

```js
/* rayane seridj
 * 5-10
 * */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw2222
  
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int month, day, year,dates,yearb;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter Date in The Format mm/dd/yyyy : ");
    month = input.nextInt();
    day = input.nextInt();
    year = input.nextInt();
    
    boolean isLeap;
    isLeap = leap(year);
    if (isLeap)
        System.out.println (year + " is a leap year ");  
    else 
        System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year");

  }
  
   public static int convertdays (int month ,int day, int year)
  {
    int yy,dd,mm,dates;
    yy =10000 *year;
    mm = 100 *month;
    dd= day;
    dates =yy + mm +dd;
    return dates;
   }

  public static boolean leap(int year)
  {
    if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 ==0 && year %100 !=0))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are they asking to do with convertdays